# Trying to Open a Website based on I1's cell value and hit tab X number of times then hit enter

Tags: excel, vba, microsoft-edge

Not great at creating a VBA code but trying to open a website via Edge based on the url in cell I1 of the worksheet, sendkeys tab 19 times (as I cant figure out how to select the website's button otherwise), hit enter, tab again 34 times, and finally hit enter. Here is the code and when I try to debug, but its showing ActiveX can't create object. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Sub OpenWebsiteAndNavigate()

```
' Declare variables
Dim edge As Object
Dim url As String
Dim i As Integer

' Get the URL from cell I1
url = Range("I1").Value

' Create a new instance of Microsoft Edge
Set edge = CreateObject("Microsoft.Edge.Application")

' Navigate to the URL
edge.navigate url

' Wait for the website to load
Do While edge.Busy Or edge.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

' Simulate keystrokes to navigate to specific elements on the website
For i = 1 To 19
    SendKeys "{TAB}"
Next i
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
For i = 1 To 34
    SendKeys "{TAB}"
Next i
SendKeys "{ENTER}"

' Wait for the website to load
Do While edge.Busy Or edge.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
```

End Sub

Expected it load the website, cycle tab 19 times and hit enter, cycle 34 times and hit enter again but ActiveX cant create ("Microsoft.Edge.Application").

Comment: You can't automate Edge in the same way you used to be able to automate Internet Explorer.  You'll need to explore using selenium or maybe a desktop tool like Power Automate.

Comment: If your solution requires send keys, it's almost always the wrong solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all i suggest you to use, `Google Chrome` instead of Edge for development purpose. as it is more developer friendy.

You should download selenium for VBA from below link & install it in your system, make sure to note down the installation location.

https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/latest

after you have installed SeleniumBasic you can find some guide here
"C:\Users\Your Name\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\Selenium.chm"

You might want to try the `WebElement.SendKeys Method` section in the documentation.

Then download microsoft edge driver from the below link
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

(make sure to download the right driver/version for your system) download the driver unzip the exe file and put it in the `SeleniumBasic` installation folder.

*** Now in VBA window goto Tools > References > select `Selenium Type Library` you must do this step.

```
Sub OpenWebsiteAndNavigate()

    Dim bot As New WebDriver
    Dim element As Selenium.WebElement

    bot.Start "chrome"
    bot.Window.Maximize ' to maximize browser window

    bot.Get (Range("I1").Value)  ' this is not recomended you should use spacific referance with sheet name or use Range object

    bot.FindElementById ("someID") ' to find some thing with ID
    bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='loginBtn']").Click  ' to find some thing with xpath
    bot.ExecuteScript ("some java script")

    bot.SendKeys ("someThing") ' to right some thing in web form

    'selects drop down
    Set element = bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='ddlModuleModal']")
    element.AsSelect.SelectByValue (110)

End Sub
```